# The graph of the following function discontinuous is connected?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, connectedness

Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ a function defined by $$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             \frac{1}{2}x+\frac{3}{4} &   si  & x \in [0,\frac{1}{2}] \\
             \\ \frac{8}{5}x - \frac{4}{5}&  si & x \in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}) \\
             \\ 3x-\frac{9}{4} &  si  & x \in [\frac{3}{4},1]
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

$f$ is not continuous but, graph of $f$ is connected?

Let $G_{f}$ graph of function $f$, so I tried to separeted that set, but I can't. And, we can see that $$G_{f}=A \cup B \cup C$$ where $A=\{(x,f(x)): f(x)> 3x-1\}$, $B=\{(x,f(x)): 3x-2 < f(x) < 3x-1\}$, $C=\{(x,f(x)): f(x) < 3x-2\}$. So I suposse $G_{f}$ is connected, could you help me to prove if I am right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Take a disk of radius 1/100 around each point, then take the union of the disks in each piece of the graph, call them $A_1,A_2,A_3$. Then $G_f=\bigcup_{i=1}^3 (A_i \cap G_f)$ is a disjoint union of sets each open in the subspace topology of $G_f$.

The point here is that the entire first piece of the graph is at least some distance from both of the other two pieces of the graph, so it can be "separated by open sets" in this way.

Comment: @KOro The graph is a disconnected subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, because (using that definition) the closures of each of the pieces of the graph are disjoint from each other.

Comment: I got that. Thanks a lot :)